# ScanF Loop Fails to Read Single Character

Tags: c, pointers, input, scanf, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a BST. (i = insert, s = search, p = print). Insert and search both take two arguments separated by a space in a line, and perform the necessary duties. However, print is only suppose to take in **one** argument, p, which then proceeds to print the tree.

Whenever I input **p** in my command line argument, or any other character really, the loop is waiting for another input. If I input i followed by a number, the program resumes. The **printf** statement doesn't even get executed, so the **ch == 'p'** doesn't even trigger. Any advice?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        char ch;
        int i;
        Node *root = NULL;
        while(scanf(" %c",&ch) != EOF) {
                if(ch == 'i') {
                        scanf(" %d", &i);
                        InsertNode(&root, newNode(i));
                }
                if(ch == 's') {
                        scanf(" %d", &i);
                        if(SearchNode(root,i) == 0) {
                                printf("absent\n");
                        }
                        else {
                                printf("present\n");
                        }
                if(ch == 'p') {
                        printf("Trying to recursively print!");
                        return 0;
                        InOrderRecursive(root);
                }
}
}

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation and you may find the problem. The `p` block is inside the `s` block. Using a debugger would also be a good idea - you can step thru the code line by line.

Comment: Also, a char type cannot hold an EOF value.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I input p in my command line argument, or any other character really, the loop is waiting for another input.

Use an auto-formatter and the reason/fix should be apparent.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char ch;
  int i;
  Node *root = NULL;
  while (scanf(" %c", &ch) != EOF) {
    if (ch == 'i') {
      scanf(" %d", &i);
      InsertNode(&root, newNode(i));
    }
    if (ch == 's') {
      scanf(" %d", &i);
      if (SearchNode(root, i) == 0) {
        printf("absent\n");
      } else {
        printf("present\n");
      } 
      if (ch == 'p') {  // this is never true.
        printf("Trying to recursively print!");
        return 0;
        InOrderRecursive(root);
      }
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```